# When tensor product of algebras is alternative

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory, tensor-products

Let $A$ and $B$ two alternative algebras, i.e. $a(ab)=(aa)b$ and $(ba)a=b(aa)$, what is needed to say that $A \otimes B$ is alternative?

Comment: Answered at [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/408680/alternativity-on-a-otimes-b). Please do not crosspost.